# Visual Studio отказывается подсвечивать код в скриптах Unity

Tags: unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Уже всё пробовал, в External tools устанавливал среду разработки и нажимал Regenerate project files, путь до проекта проверял, всё на латинице и слитно, перезапускал среду и Unity. Ничего не помогло, MonoBehaviour подсвечивается белым и подсказок нет. В комментариях под гайдами часто видел у людей такую же проблему, но ответа никто не писал.

Comment: Я слышал только о том, что это нужно как-то в самой среде исправлять, но как я не знаю

Comment: Отсутствует `IntelliSense` для `C#` версии `Unity`. Запусти `Visual Studio Installer`, у установленной `Visual Studio Community 20XX` нажми `[изменить]`, поставь галочку `Разработка игр с помощью Unity` и `[Изменить]`. Это можно было сделать при установке.